# Is it possible for moons to have their own moons?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, moons, astronomy, astrodynamics

I'm wondering, if it's possible for moons to have their own natural satellites, something big enough to be spherical? Stars have planets, planets have moons. Is it possible that moons have moons too?

Comment: Related question on [astronomy.se]: [Do moons have moons?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/856/13)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is theoretically possible, but such a satellite would probably not be in a stable orbit. Such a system is not known in the Solar system and due to gravitational perturbations it would not last long.

[Popular Science](http://www.popsci.com/scitech/article/2008-04/could-moon-have-moons)
[Astro](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=679)

Comment: Are there notable examples of such theoretical systems that would be stable?

Comment: @user1306322 Rhea's ring (see the Astronomy post linked to above by TildalWave).